# How to scrape data from page after button click with Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape data from this page, for example: http://autochess.varena.com/profile/930667105

When you click on one of the recent matches, more information about the match drops down. I've figured out how to get Selenium to click on each of the recent matches one by one without error, but I don't know how to get whatever the code is for the drop down information boxes.

`driver.page_source` just gets the source code as far as I can tell which isn't what I want.

Comment: I’m a bit confused of your intentions, perhaps edit the question to be more specific. Are you trying to get the value of a select - dropdown - element using selenium web driver?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on those drop down objects, you see something like this.
[image]

The difference between clicking the object and un-clicking the object is this.

```
<i class="auto-chess chess-xiala record-arrow"></i>

<i class="auto-chess chess-xiala record-arrow active"></i>
```

So, I'm guessing the code would look like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep

obj = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\your_path_here\\chromedriver.exe')
obj.get('http://autochess.varena.com/profile/930667105')

for p in obj.find_elements_by_class_name('i class'):
    p.click()
    sleep(1)
    obj.get('auto-chess chess-xiala record-arrow active')
    sleep(1)
```

Or, this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
select_fr = Select(webdriver.find_element_by_id("i class"))
select_fr.select_by_index(0)
```